# Checking in uninded code to tfs

Tags: tfs

- I was working on a project in visual studio 2015
- Forgot to checkin the code
- We installed a new tfs site

Now when I open the code from my hard drive I get the message that the tfs server cannot be found.

My issue is, when I use manage connections to connect to the project, the solution gets closed.  When I reopen the solution from the hard drive, the connection to tfs is lost.  Is there a sequence I need to follow to get this right?

Comment: Did you upgrade your TFS or install a new TFS? Was this project source controlled by the previous TFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Connect to new TFS in VS
2. Open Source Control Explorer and map
   the TFS folder to your existing local folder
3. Check out for edit
   on changed files
4. Check in files
5. Everything should be working

Answer (score 0):

It seems the project is source controlled by the previous TFS. Try to open the project, go to File--Source Control--Advanced--Change Source Control, and Unbind the solution and projects.

[image]